# PhantomJS screenshot error

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I'm new to using phantomjs and the headless browser libraries, I have setup a small example but I am coming across an error:

[image: The image error]

It seems to be an error with the image format rather than my actual test code, everything is referenced properly above, I thought a screenshot would be better than actually pasting the code, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The signature using `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat` is obsolete as of Selenium 3.1.0](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Screenshot_SaveAsFile_1.htm)

Comment: Ah thankyou, for anyone else it should be: phantomDriver.TakeScreenshot().SaveAsFile("LetsSnapascreenshot.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);